# Can PowerShell be used to run scripts on a remote PC?

Tags: network, windows, server, powershell

Can powershell be used to run scripts on remote PC’s like i am sitting in my house and i want to run scripts on a facebook server ,is that possible (if facebook server is using windows )?

**Question 2)**
Is is possible to have a Server Side Attack using PowerShell ?
Or only client side attack is only possible?

Comment: You can run scripts on remote PC's that you have access to..

Comment: By access to , you mean acess to the Powershell of remote pc(here facebook server)?and how can i get the access ,using server side includes or what ??

Comment: Meaning you can run remote powershell on machines on your network. Opening powershell to the internet opens your servers up to too much risk. Therefore without access to Facebook's network you cannot run Powershell commands on their servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run POWERSHELL on a remote machine.

The same can be achieved using PowerShell Remoting

PowerShell will run on any system(Windows as OS) . 
If you want to run code on a  server, you need to have firewall access to that server,otherwise your connection will be blocked , Powershell would need to be installed/pre-installed on that computer/server/machine, and the permissions in the Powershell environment would need to allow for remote scripts to be run .
Using Command Execution Vulnerability it can be exploited .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to run Powershell on a remote machine.  The technology is called Powershell Remoting (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx)

Powershell will run on any system that supports it, client or server (Only Windows, that I'm aware of).  To get access to a server, you would need to make sure you have firewall access to that server, Powershell would need to be installed, and the permissions in the Powershell environment would need to allow for remote scripts to be run (via the Set-ExecutionPolicy commandlet).  The safest way would be to use the "RemoteSigned" execution policy.

Comment: I did answer question 2.  The question was is it possible to execute Powershell on a server, and the answer is yes, provided it is installed.  .